# Karate API Testing - Numeric validation on API response array

Tags: karate

I have a response stored in one of my karate var holdingid as :

```
And def holdingID =  $GetDataSet_greaterThan_Filter_Response.rowData[*].7
```

holdingID =
 [
  21015000,
  146066000,
  10497015000,
  58765000,
  27790000,
  4.308709302E7,
  2.0360701868295E7,
  21710000,
  331720000,
  62327000,
  57210000,
  19430000,
  19129000,
  2.0168081879E8,
  35242933,
  7.0444591772E8,
  2.551241528E7,
  1.948655045E7,
  2.520400137E7,
  3.8540777658E8,
  103001450,
  1.957371122E7,
  1.6805940819E8,
  20907400,
  19500118,
  1.8480989443E8,
  181875000,
  5.609840033E7,
  6.931536767E7,
  5.32741731109984E8,
  188974032,
  591381346,
  8.419481045E7,
  19868866,
  5.5488624902E7,
  30759197,
  8.926510191E7,
  5.382712107E7,
  3.095059546E7,
  7.174669486E7,
  23828000,
  42558698,
  1.777676693E7,
  21695100,
  7.198816072E8,
  322132495,
  19120000
]

Now I need to check following operations over this with some value(for example: 17559097):

1. Greater Than 17559097
2. Greater than equals to 17559097
3. Less than 17559097
4. Less than or equals to 17559097

What I tried:

First Approach:

I did following things to find the solution:
* assert holdingID  > 17559097

This got fail with this message: assertion failed: assert evaluated to false: holdingID  > 17559097

Second Approach:
Created a list and tried to perform sorting. So that I can check first value and apply assertion over that.

```
And def listAsDescending = new ArrayList()
* eval for(var i = 0; i < holdingID.length; i++) listAsDescending.add(holdingID[i])
And print listAsDescending
* eval Collections.sort(listAsDescending)
```

But I got following error:Collections.sort(listAsDescending), java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

How to perform these operations over stored variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs carefully, there are so many ways. I leave it to you to find other ways:

```
* def holdingId = [ 21015000, 146066000, 10497015000, 58765000, 27790000, 4.308709302E7, 2.0360701868295E7, 21710000, 331720000, 62327000, 57210000, 19430000, 19129000, 2.0168081879E8, 35242933, 7.0444591772E8, 2.551241528E7, 1.948655045E7, 2.520400137E7, 3.8540777658E8, 103001450, 1.957371122E7, 1.6805940819E8, 20907400, 19500118, 1.8480989443E8, 181875000, 5.609840033E7, 6.931536767E7, 5.32741731109984E8, 188974032, 591381346, 8.419481045E7, 19868866, 5.5488624902E7, 30759197, 8.926510191E7, 5.382712107E7, 3.095059546E7, 7.174669486E7, 23828000, 42558698, 1.777676693E7, 21695100, 7.198816072E8, 322132495, 19120000 ]
* match each holdingId == '#? _ > 17559097'
* def fun = function(x){ return x > 17559097 }
* def actual = karate.filter(holdingId, fun)
* match holdingId == actual
```